# Servlet doGet return 404 on a simple get method?

Tags: jsp, servlets, http-status-code-404

I have a simple `doGet` method on a hyperlink to direct a view cart summary. It works if I run on the `servlet` the path is,

```
 http://localhost:9090/WebApp/view_cart
```

whereas if I run on the `JSP` page when I click the below hyperlink, The path is

```
<form method="GET"> <a href="view_cart"> view cart </a> </form>

http://localhost:9090/WebApp/frontend/view_cart
```

Here is a doGet method, how can I get the correct path to show the `/view_cart page`??

```
@WebServlet("/view_cart")
public class ViewCartServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ViewCartServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
                    
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        String viewCart = "frontend/shopping_cart.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(viewCart);
        rd.forward(request, response);    
    }

}
```

Comment: What about linking to `${request.contextPath}view_cart)` in your JSP file?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<a href="view_cart">
```

with

```
<a href="/view_cart">
```

So that the path can become `the-context-path/view_cart`

Comment: I need to go to root then back to the folder that I store the jsp like this <a href="../view_cart"> cart </a>

Comment: @Stu_Dent - Yes, that's the idea. I hope your problem is solved.